# Shipping methods - Local Pickup option not available when Flat Rate is hidden

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

[Based on this answer *(code below)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919165/remove-shipping-flat-rate-method-for-particular-category-woocommerce-2-6/38924979#38924979), I successfully can hide **flat rate** from particular **product category** and **local delivery** option is available. This is working perfect.

**The problem:** **local pickup option is NOT available** for that particular category.

How can I make the local pickup option available to this special category?

This is the code that I use:

```
function custom_shipping_methods( $rates ){

    // Define/replace here your correct category slug (!)
    $cat_slug = 'your_category_slug';
    $prod_cat = false;

    // Going through each item in cart to see if there is anyone of your category        
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $values ) {
        $item = $values['data'];

        if ( has_term( $cat_slug, 'product_cat', $item->id ) )
            $prod_cat = true;
    }

    $rates_arr = array();

    if ( $prod_cat ) {
        foreach($rates as $key => $rate) {
            if ('free_shipping' === $rate->method_id || 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id || 'local_delivery' === $rate->method_id) {
                $rates_arr[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return !empty( $rates_arr ) ? $rates_arr : $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_methods', 100);
```

One more thing: Is it possible to show **local delivery** and **local pickup** for that special category depending on location?

Currently in my store **local Pickup** or **Delivery** is setup only for one location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Advice:** *ONLY for WooCommerce version 2.6.x (added compatibility for WC 3+)*

After many tests… You will need to change 2 little things in your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'custom_shipping_methods', 100, 2 );
function custom_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ){

    // Define/replace here your correct category slug (!)
    $cat_slug = 'posters';
    $prod_cat = false;

    // Going through each item in cart to see if there is anyone of your category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $values ) {
        $product = $values['data'];

        // compatibility with WC +3
        $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

        if ( has_term( $cat_slug, 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            $prod_cat = true;
    }

    $rates_arr = array();

    if ( $prod_cat ) {
        foreach($rates as $rate_id => $rate) { // <== There was a mistake here

            if ('free_shipping' === $rate->method_id || 'local_pickup' === $rate->method_id || 'local_delivery' === $rate->method_id) {
                $rates_arr[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                // break; // <========= Removed this to avoid stoping the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return !empty( $rates_arr ) ? $rates_arr : $rates;
}
```

There was 2 mistakes:

- One in the foreach loop with a bad variable name that I have replace it.
- Removed `break;` avoiding stoping the foreach loop when one condition match.

---

*This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme.*

**This code is tested and fully functional** *(it will work if you have correctly set your shipping zones)*.

> **You will need to refresh shipping cached data:** disable, save and enable, save related shipping methods for the current shipping zone, in woocommerce shipping settings.

---

References:

- [Hide other shipping methods when FREE SHIPPING is available](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/)
- [WooCommerce - Hide other shipping methods when FREE SHIPPING is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38280610/woocommerce-hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-available/38281051#38281051)

Comment: @ZahidIqbal There was a stupid mistake and the `break;`… See you around :) …